# Как разбить String на отдельные слова в Java?

Tags: java, строки, парсер, сравнение, equals

Всем Привет! У меня есть такая задача, надо разделить строку на слова, записать ее в массив и затем сравнить каждый элемент с каждым в массиве (т.е. каждое слово с каждым) те которые совпали удалить, недавно прочитал о `equals()`, который отлично справляется с сравнением строк, но по какой-то причине Он не работает в массиве. `Java` начал изучать недавно, поэтому строго не судите по коду, всем Спасибо!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String b = "Привет Привет Привет";
    String s[] = b.split(" ");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].equals(s[i + 1])) {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит не работает в массиве? Вам нужно удалить дубликаты слов из строки?

Comment: я доработал уже все работает,осталось одна проблема надо удалить все те слова которые повторяются

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  
 String b = "A A A";
    String s[] = b.split(" ");
int i;
int y;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length - 1; i++) {
        for (y = i + 1; y < s.length; y++)
            if (s[i].equals(s[y])) {
     System.out.println("i=" + i + " y=" + y + " -> " + s[i]);
            }
           
    }

Comment: тогда уберите эту фразу из вопроса. Вы может использовать Set. Это автоматически избавит вас от повторов.

Comment: можно поподробней пожалуйста

Comment: создаёте Set добавляете в него элементы. Потом Set конвертируете в массив. И получаете массив без дублей.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  
 String b = "A A A".split(" ");
 
    
     HashSet<String> sa = new HashSet<>();
    sa.add(b);
    System.out.println("Размер HashSet = " + sa.size());

Comment: и как мне добавить каждое слово до пробела в мой Set? он сразу целый string добавляет

Comment: В цикле добавляйте

Answer (score 2):

Если воспользоваться возможностями Stream API, то можно решить задачу даже проще:

```
String s = ...
Stream.of(s.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+"))
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .distinct().sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант не учитывает множество пробелов. Тут надо регулярным выражением пользоваться. Извлечь все слова потом поместить в `SortedSet`. Почему в `SortedSet`? Во-первых, он не допускает дублирование, а во-вторых отсортирует все слова по возрастанию, что облегчает проверку.

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordParser {

    private static final String EXAMPLE_TEST =
            "На дворе — трава, на траве — дрова. Не руби дрова на траве двора!";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern =
                Pattern.compile("\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS 
                        | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
        SortedSet<String> words = new TreeSet<>();

        while (matcher.find())
            words.add(matcher.group().toLowerCase());

        for (String word : words)
            System.out.println("word = " + word);
    }
}
```

**"\w+"** - модификатор находит только слова, то есть исключает знаки и т.п.

**Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS** - установливает флаг на Юникоде чтобы можно было сделать поиск в любой кодировке. (Если честно не знаю как обстоят дело с поиском слов на азиатских языках как китайский, корейский, японский и т.д.)

Вот что печатает этот класс после запуска:

word = двора
word = дворе
word = дрова
word = на
word = не
word = руби
word = трава
word = траве